# В тайском тексте (tkinter text widget )не выводятся все символы

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

ubuntu 18.04. tkinter text widget.

В тайском тексте не выводятся все символы над или под буквой. Есть ли какое нибудь решение, или объяснение почему так? Вывод в виджет идет из текстового файла. В файле все знаки видны.

Так и не понял, разобрался с pyqt5, там все показывается.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -- coding: utf-8 -- 


from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
tx = Text(root, font=('times',20), width=30, height=10)
tx.pack()
tx.insert(1.0, 'ผู้ลี้ภัย')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не хватает вопросу: 1) код 2) текст 3) скриншот (желательно)

Comment: Спасибо. Код оригинальный очень большой, но этот с тем же результатом.  
#! /usr/bin/python3  
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
from tkinter import *  
root = Tk()  
tx = Text(root, font=('times',20), width=30, height=10)  
tx.pack()  
tx.insert(1.0, 'ผู้ลี้ภัย')  
root.mainloop()  
В результате в поле виджета будет - ผลภย  
Первый раз пишу вопрос, не разобрался как добавить скриншот.

Comment: Код в комментарии плохо виден, поэтому его в вопрос добавлять через кнопку `править` (ваш код туда перенес). По поподу скриншота, когда будете в редакторе вопроса увидите кнопку вставки изображения, например можно из буфера обмена вставить картинку

Comment: У меня (win7) ваш код отображается текст практически полностью -- у буквы `ลี้` вторая закорючка не отображается

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению вторая закорючка самая важная в тайском языке. Хотелось понять реально ли в tkinter показывать все. Но похоже придется все делать в pyqt5.